# 2D Vector Optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, vector

This is only a compact test case but I have a vector of doubles and I want to populate a square matrix (2D vector) of all pairwise differences. When compiled with -O3 optimization, this takes about 1.96 seconds on my computer (computed only from the nested double for-loop).

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  vector<double> a;
  vector<vector<double> > b;
  unsigned int i, j;
  unsigned int n;
  double d;

  n=10000; //In practice, this value is MUCH bigger
  a.resize(n);

  for (i=0; i< n; i++){
    a[i]=static_cast<double>(i);
  }

  b.resize(n);
  for (i=0; i< n; i++){
    b[i].resize(n);
    b[i][i]=0.0; //Zero diagonal
  }

  for (i=0; i< n; i++){
    for (j=i+1; j< n; j++){
      d=a[i]-a[j];

      //Commenting out the next two lines makes the code significantly faster
      b[i][j]=d; 
      b[j][i]=d;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However, when I comment out the two lines:

```
b[i][j]=d; 
b[j][i]=d;
```

The program completes in about 0.000003 seconds (computed only from the nested double for-loop)! I really didn't expect these two lines to be the rate-limiting-step. I've been staring at this code for a while and I'm out of ideas. Can anybody please offer any suggestions as to how I could optimize this simple piece of code so that the time can be significantly reduced?

Comment: The compiler probably optimizes your whole loop away, as you are not using the value calculated inside it for anything. Try adding the keyword `volatile` before your declaration of `double d` - things will probably get quite a bit slower after that.

Comment: "significantly faster"! If you're timings are accurate it's 653,333 times faster! jlahd's given the reason for that. One way to actually make it faster is to use a triangular array since you're storing the same number in two different places.

Comment: Would linearizing the vector make it even faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you comment out those two lines, all that's left in the nested loop is to keep computing `d` and then throwing away the result. Since this can't have any effect on the behaviour of the program, the compiler will just optimize out the nested loop. That's why the program finishes almost instantaneously.

In fact, I confirmed this by compiling the code twice with `g++ -O3`, once with only the `d=a[i]-a[j]` statement in the nested loop, and once with the nested loop deleted entirely. The code emitted was identical.

Nevertheless, your code is currently slower than it has to be, because it's missing the cache. When you access a two-dimensional array in a nested loop like this, you should always arrange for the iteration to be continuous through memory if possible. This means that the second index should be the one that's varying faster. The access to `b[j][i]` is violating this rule and missing the cache. So let's rewrite.

Before:

```
for (i=0; i< n; i++){
    for (j=i+1; j< n; j++){
        d=a[i]-a[j];
        b[i][j]=d; 
        b[j][i]=d;
    }
}
```

Timing:

```
real    0m1.026s
user    0m0.824s
sys     0m0.196s
```

After:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        b[i][j] = a[j] - a[i];
    }
    for (j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
        b[i][j] = a[i] - a[j];
    }
}
```

Timing:

```
real    0m0.335s
user    0m0.164s
sys     0m0.164s
```

Comment: That's very interesting. And here I thought I was saving time by only computing the upper triangle and then copying over the result to the lower triangle. Instead, I should be leveraging memory cache! Is that right?

Comment: Yep. Good cache behaviour is a must when doing heavy numerical computation like this.

Comment: Should the first nested for loop be `b[i][j]=a[i]-a[j]`?

Comment: No, I don't think so. b[i][j]=a[j]-a[i] is equivalent to b[j][i]=a[i]-a[j] where the ranges of i and j are interchanged and that should correspond to the statement b[j][i]=d in the original... but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: But hey, it's *your* program. If you *want* it to be a[i]-a[j], go ahead.